# Is there any way to get number of ipv4 forwarded packets via netlink?

Tags: statistics, ipv4, netlink

i need a network routing statistics, and im using netlink for the interface statistics. I need the number of packets forwarded on an interface using netlink if it is posible, or can someone suggest another solution on how to get these counter statistics? Thanks

Ive tried to retreive them with netlink, and so far i got just the interface related statistics, such as tx_bytes, rx_bytes, and i need the number of ipv4 forwarded packet.